# Regarding a new chat room

Tags: discussion, chat

For many (but not necessarily all) Indian students, the biggest motivation to understand political science is the UPSC exam. I have started a new chat room, so my question is *is this kind of room okay?*

The exam requires good knowledge of world-level and India-level social and political science knowledge.

https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102008/civil-service-examination

Comment: Not even a single comment or answer come on?

Comment: Should I need to put to bounty on question?

Comment: #JackRod you can’t put bounties questions on a per-site meta

Answer (score 1):

The room has been quite active for a month now. If there has been no moderator intervention or negative comments, I think you can safely assume all is well.